# Need help with what non-op players can do in an MC server im making

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way that a non-op player can click a clickEvent command in the book he is given but not be able to do any other commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clickEvent` executes as if the player executed it themselves, meaning that for example only OPed players can click a text in a book and execute "cheat" commands with it. If you want to selectively allow other commands to be triggered, use `/trigger`.

Comment: i''m not exactly sure how that works, i did put /trigger in front of my command but it doesn't work, could u elaborate

Comment: You can't just invent any syntax you like. Look up the correct one in the wiki.