# Minecraft - Branching Dialogue using Tellraw and Triggers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to set up a system of branching dialogue using command blocks, tellraw, and triggers.

Players are presented with a series of questions and answers. In this case, the sentence says, "Do you like scrambled eggs? YES or NO"

I want players to be able to click on "YES" or "NO"

I have a series of chain command blocks which work fine for me (the opped owner of the server).

```
execute if score @p TEST matches 1 run tellraw @p ["","Do you like scrambled eggs? ",{"text":"YES","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players set @p TEST 2"}}," or ",{"text":"NO","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players set @p TEST 3"}},""]

execute if score @p TEST matches 2 run tellraw @p "I like eggs too!"

execute if score @p TEST matches 3 run tellraw @p "Too bad!"
```

However, when players on my server use these command blocks, they are unable to click on "YES" or "NO." They see the question appear, but are unable to activate the click event when they click on an answer.

I know that I need to change the click event code to a trigger, but I am not sure how to do this. Here is the code I have tried--but it does not work:

```
execute if score @p TEST matches 1 run tellraw @p ["","Do you like scrambled eggs? ",{"text":"YES","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger TEST set 2"}}," or ",{"text":"NO","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger TEST set 3"}},""]
```

I have already set up the scoreboard TEST as a trigger. I also have a command block that enables the trigger for all players. Even so, I cannot get the click event to function as a trigger. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help with what non-op players can do in an MC server im making](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355763/need-help-with-what-non-op-players-can-do-in-an-mc-server-im-making) **EDIT**: I take that back, OP already tried this and is asking for help with the specifics of the implementation of said solution.

Comment: What kind of error message do the non-op players get when clicking? And does it work for OP players?

Comment: I don't have the exact error message (since none of my players are online right now). When they click on the text they get the error "Unknown or Incomplete command" followed by a portion of the command that they cannot run. I will respond a little later (when I have a player online to test for me) and provide the exact error.

Comment: When my players try the first set of command blocks, they get the error "Unknown or Incomplete command, see below for error: scoreboard players set @p TEST 2 <--[HERE]." When my players try the second set of commands blocks, they get the exact same error. Both sets of command blocks work for me (the opped owner of the server).

Comment: ah right. You see, in order for players to `trigger` a scoreboard, they need to use the `/trigger` command to do that. It seems correct in your explanation above, but your comment now seems to suggest that you're using the `/scoreboard` command inside the clickevent instead.

Comment: I have tried using the /scoreboard command and the /trigger command. The trigger command gives the same error. Here is the command I have tried (also listed above):


execute if score @p TEST matches 1 run tellraw @p ["","Do you like scrambled eggs? ",{"text":"YES","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger TEST set 2"}}," or ",{"text":"NO","bold":true,"color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger TEST set 3"}},""]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145343/discussion-between-plagiatus-and-megan).